# javascript typeof null isnt working as expected

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am having an object of objects where each object has a key and an array as a value. This is what I was having [image](https://ibb.co/m96MPPB). I had some arrays with values less than `x` elements (in this case it's `20`) in each array so I wrote this code to pad my arrays with zeros. here is the output of my code [image](https://ibb.co/NTHgv0P). However, as you can see, the code isnt working when having an array with `null` values only. This has put me off for a while.
here is my code:

```
let results[tab] = {
    "Capital Cost ($)": [-2176346066.1517634],
    "Electricity Revenue ($)": 
    [25128866.14469719, 34695653.93022109, 42581870.9302151, 48994313.58438795],
"Net Present Value ($)": [null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null]
}

const maxLength = Object.values(results[tab]).map( x => x.map( x=> x === null ? 0 : x))
                .reduce( (acc, item) => Math.max(acc, item.length), 0);
const new_values = Object.values(results[tab]).map( value => value.concat(Array(maxLength - value.length).fill(0)));
const keys = Object.keys(results[tab]);
var toObj = (ks, vs) => ks.reduce((o,k,i)=> {o[k] = vs[i]; return o;}, {});
const new_results = toObj(keys, new_values);
console.log(new_results)
```

**Solution**: So It turned out that `map` doesnt apply the new condition. Solved!

Comment: `typeof` always returns a **string**, so it will never be `null`.

Comment: Please format the code properly. Do not expect anyone to read that in its current state.

Comment: I'd help but I'm not going to reformat the code, if you want to check for null just do

if (something === null) or if (!something)

Comment: You can't set `const results[tab]`, you could only say it like this `const results =[];
let tab =1; results[tab] = ...`.

Comment: @Sascha that was just to give a hint, thank you

Comment: @samerhassan you also removed typeof which was mentioned in my answer.

Comment: @AakashGarg yeah, sorry for that, you got your reward again ;)

Answer (score 1):

type of x can never be null, as null is a value not a type. even the type of null is object. so there is no need of typeof in your code.

Comment: upvoted but please add the correct code also (`x === null`)

Comment: poor js background, I tried that but still doesnt work! same output